# Working with Firefox add-on builder without Python

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

One of FF add-on SDK installation prerequisites is having Python path (2.5 or 2.6 versions). I'm not intending to work with Python to develop add-on, but rather I'm more interested in working with JS, Ajax, JQ, PHP and SQL (on the server side), HTML and CSS. I don't want to use Pyhon code. Is it possible to work with Firefox add-on builder and to create toolbar without using Python? Would I still need having Python installed on my computer? Some help with clearing things would be appreciated-don't hesitate to get into details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide first: are you going to work with the Add-on SDK or the Add-on Builder?

1. Add-on SDK is an extension building framework. You don't use Python to write the extension but Python is required to run the scripts that will package your extension. So, if you want to work with Add-on SDK directly you will have to install Python.
2. Add-on Builder is a web application that allows you create SDK-based extensions via a web interface. You don't need Python to use the Add-on Builder because the extension package is created on the builder.addons.mozilla.org server in this case and it already has Python installed.

I hope that this resolved your confusion...

Comment: Wlad, great answers (!) and I thank you a lot about it. However naturally the answers you gave lead to another new one: What is the better option-working with the add on SDK or with the add on builder? What are the differences? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GiladSabo: Well, what are you more comfortable with? Do you want to type the extension code into a web interface and let it handle versioning/packaging for you or do you prefer to use your own text editor and package the extension with a command line tool? See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder